# Allow SQLite INSERT be optional for Integer (Swift 3)

Tags: sqlite, swift3

I have the below insert line being used to save data from the IB, but the way it currently is, all of the Int fields must be completed or I get a "found an optional nil" error.  How can I set this up so that the fields with integers are not required?

```
@IBOutlet weak var diveSiteTextfield: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var diveDurationTextfield: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var diveMaxDepthTextfield: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var diveMaxDepthSymbolTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var diveDateTextfield: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var diveTimeTextfield: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var diveBuddyTextfield: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var diveCityTextfield: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var diveCountryTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var diveBodyOfWaterTextfield: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var diveLocationTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var airTypeResultTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var circuitTypeTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var tankStartTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var tankStartSymbolTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var tankEndTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var tankEndSymbolTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var weightTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var weightSymbolTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var suitTypeTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var entryTypeTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var waterTypeTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var waterTempTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var waterTempSymbolTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var currentTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var visibilityTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var airTempTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var airTempSymbolTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var weatherTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var surfaceTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var diveTypeTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var diveMasterTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var diveMasterIDTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var diveCenterTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var diveBoatTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var diveTripTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var diveNotesTextView: UITextView!



let insert = String(format:"INSERT INTO Dives (dive_number, dive_site, duration, max_depth, max_depth_symbol, dive_buddy, city, country, body_of_water, starting_tank, starting_tank_symbol, ending_tank, ending_tank_symbol, weight, weight_symbol, water_temp, water_temp_symbol, air_temp, air_temp_symbol, dive_master, dive_master_id, dive_center, boat_operator, trip_operator, dive_date, dive_time) VALUES ('\(Int(self.diveNumber))', '\(self.diveSiteTextfield.text!)', '\(Int(self.diveDurationTextfield.text!)!)', '\(Int(self.diveMaxDepthTextfield.text!)!)', '\(self.diveMaxDepthSymbolTextField.text!)', '\(self.diveBuddyTextfield.text!)', '\(self.diveCityTextfield.text!)', '\(self.diveCountryTextField.text!)', '\(self.diveBodyOfWaterTextfield.text!)', '\(Int(self.tankStartTextField.text!)!)', '\(self.tankStartSymbolTextField.text!)', '\(Int(self.tankEndTextField.text!)!)', '\(self.tankEndSymbolTextField.text!)', '\(Int(self.weightTextField.text!)!)', '\(self.weightSymbolTextField.text!)', '\(Int(self.waterTempTextField.text!)!)', '\(self.waterTempSymbolTextField.text!)', '\(Int(self.airTempTextField.text!)!)', '\(self.airTempSymbolTextField.text!)', '\(self.diveMasterTextField.text!)', '\(self.diveMasterIDTextField.text!)', '\(self.diveCenterTextField.text!)', '\(self.diveBoatTextField.text!)', '\(self.diveTripTextField.text!)', '\(self.diveDateTextfield.text!)', '\(self.diveTimeTextfield.text!)')")
```

Comment: e.g. `Int(self.airTempTextField.text!) ?? 0` !?

Comment: That worked.  Thanks.  Move to an answer please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `null coalescing operator`, e.g.

```
Int(self.airTempTextField.text!) ?? 0
```

That way you can deal with textfields which did not get any input are did get wrong input which is not parseable as integer.